# How to compare two objects in a class

Tags: class, object, methods, compare

I am beginning to write my own classes and so far I have an author class that has two strings(first and last name) and two integers (birth and death year). Now I have written another class, books, and it has an author object named bookAuthor. So, this is my code could you help fix my NullPointerException.

```
public class Author{
      String authorFirstName;
      String authorLastName;
      int authorBirth;
      int authorDeath;

      //creates a new author object with nothing set
      public Author(){
      }

      //String l=last name, String f=frist name
      //creates new author object by setting the last and first name
      public Author(String l, String f){
        authorLastName=l;
        authroFirstName=f;
      }

      //returns a string that is the first name of the author
      public String getFirstName(){
        return authorFirstName;
      }

      //return a string that is the last name of the author
      public String getLastName(){
        return authorLastName;
      }

      //int b=year of birth for author
      //sets the birth year of author and returns nothing
      public void setDates(int b){
        if (b<-2000){
          authorBirth=-40000;
        }else{
          authorBirth=b;
        }
      }

      //int b,d represent the authors year of birth and death respectively
      //returns nothing but sets the authors year of death and birth
      public void setDates(int b, int d){
        if(d>=b||birth<-2000){
          authorBirth=-4000;
          authorDeath==-4000;
        }else{
          authorBirth=b;
          authorDeath=d;
        }
      }

      //returns an int that represents the birth year of the author
      public int getBirth(){
        return authorBirth;
      }

      //returns an int that represents the death year of the author
      public int getDeath(){
        return authorDeath;
      }

      //compares two authors and if they have the same first and last name then it returns 0.
      //it also returns 0 if one of the authors appreviates his or her name by the first letter of their first name.
      public int compareTo(Author a1){
        int compareValue=1;
        if(a1.getFirstName().equals(authorFirstName)&&a1.getLastName().equals(authorLastName)){
          compareValue=0;
        }
        if(a1.charAt(0)==authorFirstName.charAt(0)&&a1.getLastName().equals(authorLastName)){
          compareValue=0;
        }
        return compareValue;
      }

      //returns a String in the form of the authors name by last name, first name
      public String toString(){
        String name=authorLastName+", "+authorFirstName;
        return name;
      }

      //returns a string of the last name, first name of the author
      //if the birth year is known it returns last name, first name of the author but input birth by (b.____)
      //if birth and death are known then returns last name, first name of the author with (birth-death)
      public String printAuthorInfo(){
        String name=authorLastName+", "+authorFirstName;
        if(authorBirth=this.getBirth()){
          name=name+" (b. "+authorBirth+")";
        }
        if(authorDeath=this.getDeath()){
          name=authorLastName+", "+authorFirstName+"("+authorBirth+"-"+authorDeath+")";
        }
        return name;
      }

      //end of Author class
    }
    public class Book{
      int bookYearPublish;
      Author bookAuthor;
      String bookNumberISBN;
      String bookTitle;

      public Book(){
      }

      //String t is the title of the book
      //creats a Book object with a title
      public Book(String t){
        bookTitle=t;
      }

      //String t is the title of the book
      //Author a is the author of the book
      //creats a Book object with a title and author
      public Book(String t, Author a){
        bookTitle=t;
        bookAuthor=a;
      }

      //String t is the title of the book
      //creates a title for a Book object
      //returns nothing but sets the title of the Book object
      //if no title was set then the title is "TITLE NOT SET"
      public void setTitle(String t){
        if (t.length()==0){
          bookTitle="TITLE NOT SET";
        }else{
          bookTitle=t;
        }
      }

      //returns a String that represents the title of the Book
      public String getTitle(){
        return bookTitle;
      }

      //Author a is the author that will be set for the Book
      //sets the author of the book
      public void setAuthor(Author a){
        bookAuthor=a;
      }

      //returns the Author of the Book
      public Author getAuthor(){
        return bookAuthor;
      }

      //int p is the year of publication of the Book
      //returns nothing
      //sets the year of publication for the Book
      public void setYear(int p){
        if (p<-2000||p>2018){
          bookYearPublish=-4000;
        }else{
          bookYearPublish=p;
        }
      }

      //returns an int that represents the year it was published
      public int getYear(){
        return bookYearPublish;
      }

      //String i is the ISBN number
      //returns nothing but sets the ISBN for the book
      //if the ISBN number is not length 13 or 10 the ISBN is "ISBN NOT SET"
      public void setISBN(String i){
        if(i.length()==13||i.length()==10){
          bookNumberISBN=i;
        }else{
          bookNumberISBN="ISBN NOT SET";
        }
      }

      //returns a String that represents the ISBN number of the book
      public String getISBN(){
        return bookNumberISBN;
      }

      //Book b is the book that is being checked if it has the same author
      //returns a boolean true if a book has two authors who are the same
      public boolean sameAuthor(Book b){
        boolean compareValue=false;
        if(b.getAuthor().compareTo(bookAuthor)==0){
          compareValue=true;
        }
      return compareValue;
      }

      //Book b is the book that is being compared to by the ISBN number
      //compares two books by relating thier ISBN numbers and returns 0 is they are the same
      public int compareTo(Book b){
        int compareValue=1;
        if(bookNumberISBN.equals(b.getISBN())){
          compareValue=0;
        }
        return compareValue;
      }

      //returns the title of Book
      //if the author is known returns a String in the form of title. last name, first name of author
      //if the year is known returns a String in the form title (year). last name, first name of author
      public String toString(){
        String title=bookTitle;
        if(bookAuthor.equals(this.getAuthor())){
          title=title+". "+bookAuthor;
        }
        if(bookYearPublish.equals(this.getYear())){
          title=bookTitle+" ("+bookYearPublish+"). "+bookAuthor;
        }
        return title;
      }

      //ends class Book
    }
```

the .getAuthor() method is a method in the Book class that returns the author of that book
my real question is how to tell my program "if something has been set then do this" for example in my code I am trying to tell my program if a title has been set for the Book then return the title...furthermore, if the year of publication has been set then return the title as described above.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error?

Comment: if you meant where the error is occurring I did as a comment on that line

Comment: either your bookAuthor is null or getAuthor() is returning null

Comment: better u post ur  complete code .may be code is not as per ur logic

Answer (score 0):

```
public String toString(){

      String title= (bookTitle==null) ? "" : bookTitle;

      if (getYear() != null && this.getYear().equals(bookYearPublish)) {
           title +=" ("+bookYearPublish+")";
      }

      title += ".";

      if (getAuthor() != null && this.getAuthor().equals(bookAuthor)) {
          title +=" "+bookAuthor;
      }

      return title;
}
```